# How to implement Blazor Mention component

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I would like to implement a blazor mention component.So in a textbox when we type @ to have a dropdown with a list of possible choices. For the dropdown elements I would like to have a template with image and text in it.

Any ideas how could I start that?

Comment: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/mention/getting-started

Comment: @TinyWang I would like to implement my own, instead of using a paid third party, or do you know a free one?

Comment: An autocomplete component with an onkeydown listening for @.

Comment: per my searching now I haven't found a free library yet. We might have to implement it by ourselves then. In this scenario, the auto complete mention componenet should have the searching feature to search for the current input text in users, then we need to monitor the input onchange event and execute the query and list result. Then we need to fix the component beside the inputbox. we might refer to how the autocomplete component designed:https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/autocomplete#:~:text=The%20Autocomplete%20component%20provides%20suggestions,a%20user%20captures%20a%20value.

Comment: So what have your tried.  How far have you got?  For starters, here's a link to an autocomplete control of mine. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5351256/Building-a-Blazor-Autocomplete-Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I ended up with the following code, I will improve it over time but it gives you the idea:

```
@code {
    private string InputText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private bool ShowSuggestions { get; set; } = false;
    private List<string> Suggestions = new List<string> { "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David" };
    private List<string> FilteredSuggestions = new List<string>();

    private void OnInputTextChanged()
    {
        if (InputText.Contains("@"))
        {
            ShowSuggestions = true;
            var mentionText = InputText.Split('@').Last();
            FilteredSuggestions = Suggestions.Where(s => s.StartsWith(mentionText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowSuggestions = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnSuggestionClicked(string suggestion)
    {
        var mentionText = InputText.Split('@').Last();
        InputText = InputText.Replace("@" + mentionText, "@" + suggestion);
        ShowSuggestions = false;
    }
}

<div class="mention-container">
    <textarea @bind-value="InputText" @bind-value:event="oninput" @oninput="OnInputTextChanged"></textarea>
    @if (ShowSuggestions)
    {
        <div class="suggestions">
            @foreach (var suggestion in FilteredSuggestions)
            {
                <div @onclick="() => OnSuggestionClicked(suggestion)">
                    @suggestion
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

<style>
    .mention-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .suggestions {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .suggestions div {
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .suggestions div:hover {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
</style>
```